# TextBoxWatermarkExtender

Tags: asp.net

i am new to asp.net and i was to work in AjaxControlToolkit and i instaled and performed other operation but it is showing me report...,

**error is:**

```
    The type name 'TextBoxWatermarkExtender' does not exist in the type 'AjaxControlToolkit'

  protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.TextBoxWatermarkExtender TextBoxWatermarkExtender1;
```

**code is:**

```
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="TBWEDOB" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtDOB"
                    watermarktext="dd/mm/yy" watermarkcssclass="watermarked"> </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

plz any one pelp me on this flow....,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided much information so it will be tough to identify where your mistake is, here's a simple step-by-step list of how you can use AJAX in your application, just follow the points below and it will work:

1) Download AJAX from [codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/), save and unzip anywhere on your machine

2) In Visual Studio Toolbox, Right click-> Add Tab, give it a name

3) Right click the newly created tab -> Choose Items...

4) Click Browse, find AjaxControlToolkit.dll and click OK

5) If all is well the controls will be added to your toolbox

6) Drag and drop a ToolkitScriptManager to the .aspx page, doing this will automatically:

6.1) Add a AjaxControlToolkit.dll reference to your project

6.2) Add the following line to the source view of your page

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

7)Drag and drop a TextBoxWatermarkExtender to the .aspx page and you're done:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="watermark" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtName" WatermarkText="Type name here..." />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
```

Comment: it still showing me erroe in it and the error is    protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.TextBoxWatermarkExtender TextBoxWatermarkExtender1;

Comment: I've created a sample project for you and uploaded it to Google drive, follow this URL - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iPiW5jXDdPeU03Skl5Y3VHZkE/edit click File->Download.Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
First Check This 
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

in Your Page and see  what is the TagPrefix in your page and than use that.like

```
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TBWE2" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TextBox1"
    WatermarkText="Type First Name Here"
    WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />

it will work defiantly
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply try `placeholder` property to achieve the watermark in input fields.

Yes, There is a restriction of older browser, so if you are working with newer version (suppots HTML 5) then you can use it like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I AM SORRY TO SAW IT IS STILL SHOWING ME THE SAME ERROR...,

Comment: jsfiddle.net/rHUHY IT IS ALSO NOT WORKING...,

Comment: in which borwser and version, you are testing..?

Answer (score 1):

try modifying the tag prefix

on the top of the page register the ajax tool kit.

```
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>

<ajax:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="TBWEDOB" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtDOB"
                    watermarktext="dd/mm/yy" watermarkcssclass="watermarked"> </ajax:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

Comment: I AM SORRY TO SAW IT IS STILL SHOWING ME THE SAME ERROR...,